# How Do We Parse Info From These Web Pages?

Tags: android, html, webview, jsoup

me and my friend need help with a little application we're trying to create for a school project. Firstly, purpose of this application is finding pharmacy around where we live. These two are the sites that I'm trying to pull information from (is this called pulling?)

http://www.istanbulsaglik.gov.tr/w/nobet/liste.asp?lc=0&gun=09.05.2015

- gun = day/date
- lc = id of town
- cs is given to a town daily and changes daily, it's just a number.

in this page.

AND/OR

http://www.nobetcieczanebul.com/

this one 'looks' much more easier to obtain required info. from.

They both contain the info that I need; name of the pharmacy, it's address and maybe phone numbers. By using JSOUP I'm hoping to parse (pull?) those information but I need help. My first priority is using 'webview'.

First we'll read cs from HTML, after that we'll put the cs into the code and call all the names, dates and addresses of pharmacy stores.

Here's my example code, this one calls id 32 town of date 05/05/2015 which contains name etc.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnGetir;
ProgressBar pb;
TextView tv;
Button btnNobet;
TextView tvNobet;
WebView wv;

class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
String Title;
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
tv.setText(Title);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        Document myDoc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.ticaret.edu.tr").get();
        Title=myDoc.title();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
   }

   class myNobettask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String Title;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wv.loadData(Title, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document myDoc= Jsoup.connect("http://apps.istanbulsaglik.gov.tr/eczane/GetNobetciEczaneler.aspx?lc=32&gun=05.05.2015&cs=6e79f453").get();


            Title=myDoc.html();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btnGetir=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTitleGetir);
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSonuc);
    pb=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    btnNobet =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNobetci);
    tvNobet=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNobetci);
wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    btnGetir.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mytask newtask= new mytask();
            newtask.execute();
        }
    });


    btnNobet.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myNobettask task= new myNobettask();
            task.execute();
        }
    });
 }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it obligatory to use one of this websites ? , because you can use `Google Places API`, more efficient and provides a json o xml response ( easy to parse )

Comment: I "believe" so because we're trying to find pharmacy on duty. Don't know if this is the right way to say it, pharmacy on duty --> drugstore that is open all day and all night, emergency pharmacy. And those two websites are the ones that show it. Does Google Places API show them?

Comment: Here's a list of all types that Google's API can provide : https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: Hmm, you are right we can use this, do you have any example codes that we can impelement into ours?

Comment: I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

With JSoup you should be able to specify which CSS selectors/ HTML components you wish to parse.

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // This should return a collection of links.`

It is possible to specify further so perhaps you wish to return a subset of all paragraph tags, you could then specify:

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Elements linksInPTags= doc.select("p > a[href]");`

Read through the [Jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/). It's pretty clear and really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) that may extremely helps :

```
    public static void makeRequest(String url)
    {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader.readLine()
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Steps to accomplish :

1 - You have to generate URL which performs your need ( as an example : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere ) 
( a full description of creating the URL exists in the link above )

2 - It's optional but more reliable to use this method in a background thread

3 - You have to parse the response ( response can be in json or xml format you can choose it from the URL ) data to perform your needs ( you can get response fields description from the link above )